# How to delete duplicated rows, and keep one row, which has constraint in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to delete all but one rows, and to keep those row which has a constraint in another table (also maybe multiple rows has constraints in another tabe)

I just used this script for presenting the data:

```
SELECT 
    E.ID, 
    E.EmployeeId, 
    E.DailyWorkingTemplateId, 
    E.EMployeeWorkingWeekId, 
    T.rank
    --,s.* --(Schedule table)
FROM EMployeeWorkingDay E
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT *, 
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId, 
                                     DailyWorkingTemplateId, 
                                     EMployeeWorkingWeekId
            ORDER BY id) rank
     FROM EmployeeWorkingDay 
    ) T ON E.ID = t.ID

--inner join Schedule s on E.Id = s.EmployeeWorkingDayId (Table Schedule has FK column on table EmployeeWorkingDay)
```

and after this command I have this sorten dataset:

```
ID     EmployeeId   DailyWorkingTemplateId  EMployeeWorkingWeekId   rank
=====  ==========  ======================== =====================  ======
29847   3721        1240                    6836                     1
29848   3721        1240                    6836                     2
29850   3721        1240                    6836                     3
29853   3721        1240                    6837                     1
29854   3721        1240                    6837                     2
29855   3721        1240                    6837                     3
29856   3721        1240                    6837                     4
29857   3721        1240                    6837                     5
```

I know how to delete those rows, where `rank > 1` but I dont know which rows has constraint to my table `Schedule`

I believe that approach lies in `left join` command and then to ask which Id's are not in this table? But I stuck here

How to check if there possible constraint before deletion?

Comment: check using `NOT EXISTS()` on table `Schedule`

Comment: You posted this already, please do not repost just because you got downvotes

Comment: This is not the same question.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I came up with:

```sql
with EmployeeWorkingDay as (
    select * from (values
        (1, 1, 1, 1),
        (2, 1, 1, 1),
        (3, 1, 1, 1),
        (4, 2, 1, 1),
        (5, 2, 1, 1)
    ) as x(ID, EmployeeID, DailyWorkingTemplateId, EMployeeWorkingWeekId)
),
Schedule as (
    select * from (values
        (1, 2),
        (2, 4)
    ) as x(Id, EmployeeWorkingDayId)
),
cte as (
    SELECT 
        E.ID, 
        E.EmployeeId, 
        E.DailyWorkingTemplateId, 
        E.EMployeeWorkingWeekId, 
        RANK() OVER(
            PARTITION BY 
                EmployeeId, 
                DailyWorkingTemplateId, 
                EMployeeWorkingWeekId
            ORDER BY s.id desc, e.id
        ) as rank
    
    FROM EmployeeWorkingDay E
    left join Schedule s
        on E.Id = s.EmployeeWorkingDayId 
)
select *
from cte
order by EmployeeId, [rank];
```

Why does this work? From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on `ORDER BY`:

> Null values are treated as the lowest possible values.

Using that fact and that we know that the `LEFT JOIN` will return a NULL for non-matching rows, doing `ORDER by s.ID desc` means that literally any match from s will sort before the non-matches. Meaning that we'll prefer to keep the one that rows in the Schedule table match to over the ones that don't.

Note - I've written it as a select so that it's easy to verify the result set. Once you're ready to do the delete, just turn that into

```sql
delete
from cte
where [rank] > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have only just one question. If theres none FK for this duplicated rows, it will delete all but one row will still be there (rank 1)? And for example if there are some constraints on duplicated rows (fk on rank 1,3,5 and total rank is 7) it will deletes ranks 2,4,6,7 right?

Comment: And can you please write the real-example (instead of this dummy data, to reference to real columns) ?

Comment: View or function 'cte' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Comment: In re: no referenced rows, I believe so. All of the rows EmployeeWorkingDay will have no match and so will use e.id as the sorting criterion. Kind of like `select * from People where FamilyName = 'AAA' order by FamilyName, GivenName;`  In re: dummy data, I did the best I could to match your situation (i.e. I named my CTEs after your tables). At this point *you* have more "real" data than I do. And in re: "multiple base tables", you're right. You can two-step it though. i.e. select the IDs that need to be deleted into a temp table and then delete based on those IDs.